# EPERM on .Trash when using eas build

Tags: react-native, macos, visual-studio-code, expo

I tired to run `eas build` but I keep getting the error `EPERM: operation not permitted, scandir '/.Trash'` I have no clue what's the reason, here's the error

```
  muhammedsowan@Muhammeds-Mac-mini coach-admin-app %  EAS build 
✔ Select platform › Android
✔ Using remote Android credentials (Expo server)
✔ Using Keystore from configuration: Build Credentials WVpHwlx0HX (default)

Compressing project files and uploading to EAS Build. Learn more
EPERM: operation not permitted, scandir '/Users/muhammedsowan/.Trash'
    Error: build command failed.
```

I tired to search for a solve online and found nothing, can anyone help me? I'm using expo on Mac

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes do on the dir of your folder:

```
git init
git add .
git commit -m "Initial commit"
```

Comment: git init
git add .
git commit -m "Initial commit"

Then try building it